# how to store db link results in oracle cache

Tags: database, oracle, caching, oracle11g

In the system, there are couple oracle DB servers.

Lets say oracle Db1 is a primary server having one master table and rest of the oracle Db servers connect to this primary server using DB link.
So is there way to cache the value fetched from primary DB into target DB so that every time a DB link call is saved and value can be fetched from local oracle DB cache.

What are the various caching mechanisms available,if any along with its advantages & disadvantages?

Does this caching works seamlessly in Active- Passive node setup or any additional config settings/code is needed ?

When primary DB value changes, the consumer DBs to be notified of change so as to flush the data from cache. So any event driven mechanism possible.

Environment details - Oracle 11g Database Release1, Unix.

Would appreciate inputs with sample code snippet on "HowTo". Thank you

Comment: A `MATERIALIZED VIEW` is one that comes closer to what you are expecting. however it is not exactly caching in computing sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow an application to continue working when a database link is temporarily offline is to use a Materialized View (MV).

This does not work like a cache, however, as the MV would need to be refreshed manually on a schedule (e.g. once every 5 minutes). If the data on the remote database changes, the local database will not see the new results until the MV is refreshed.

For example:

```
create materialized view tablename_mv
  refresh complete on demand
  as select * from remotetablename@dblinkname;
```

Then refresh it periodically with:

```
begin
  dbms_mview.refresh('TABLENAME_MV');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs. T data to b shared between primary & other DBs is very less (5-10 rows with single column).So will Result Cache be good option?

Comment: If you're talking about the SQL Result Cache, that won't work as the cache will not be invalidated based on the status of the database link.

Comment: Since your dataset is very small, I might go with an MV with a fast refresh interval, e.g. 1 minute.

Comment: thanks again ! shall consider option suggested by you.